How can I benchmark different portions of a PyTorch training script?
Set Up
I have an image classifier training on my M3 MacBook Air using the exact same code as I ran today in Google Colab. Google gave me a T4 GPU and not including up/downloading data, the Colab script took ~6x longer than on my MacBook. This strictly contradicts this blog post graphic and my intuitions on consumer vs. production hardware. The graphic actually shows an M2 max (a much better chip than mine) as being comparable to a 2018 T4.



Provider
Google Colab
My Macbook Air (8 GB)




Hardware
T4 GPU
M3 (Base)


Train Script Runtime
~22 min
~3.5 min



My suspicion is that even though the compute isn't quite as good, I get the speed up from Apple's unified RAM/vRAM set up, saving time not moving image tensors onto a GPU because they're already on the GPU. Is that right? If so it would mean moving tensors on/off the GPU constitues about ((22-3)/22 =) 86% of the train time, which is crazy, and I have trouble believing.
Final question:
Does anyone have any insights into:
A) Where the speed up is coming from?
B) What libraries/functions I can use to benchmark different parts of my code other than just python's time module?
I feel like timeit isn't the move either, because I don't want to run both training scripts 100+ times. Maybe something PyTorch internal? I'm curious to pick apart the training loop and identify if certain other portions of the train loop are performing better on the M3 than is possible with the T4.
Edit: I should mention the network is small: 2 hidden layers dimensions cwh->1000, 1000->10. Maybe that’s why training could be such a small percentage of the overall compute?
